# Contours of points not detected properly

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I have an image (see attached) which consists of 12 black dots on a white surface. The dots are not regular and not single pixels. Using following code I try to find the dots:

```
// black dots on white ground:
const double th=cv::threshold(srcImg,threshedImg,100, 255,CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV|CV_THRESH_OTSU);
cv::findContours(threshedImg,contours,CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Amazingly "contours" does not return 12 elements but 16 (each of these elements itself consists of two Points). When looking into the returned contours-data, I find things like this:

```
+       [0] {x=662 y=298 }  cv::Point_<int>
+       [1] {x=673 y=298 }  cv::Point_<int>

+       [0] {x=662 y=295 }  cv::Point_<int>
+       [1] {x=673 y=295 }  cv::Point_<int>
```

This would be an exmplanation for the too much returned contours, here instead of these two elements I would have expected one which looks like this:

```
+       [0] {x=662 y=298 }  cv::Point_<int>
+       [1] {x=673 y=295 }  cv::Point_<int>
```

But more than this, for all these pairs of Points y is always the same. So it seems the dots are detected with their horizontal extension only, but not with their height. What could be the reason for this? What needs t obe modified to let OpenCV detect the shapes/contours/bounds properly?

Thank you :-)

The dots I try to detect: [image]

Comment: can you upload the threshold image? You can draw the contours with `cv::drawContours` for finding out what has been detected, which is nice for debugging.

Comment: can you show the code how you print those contours?

Comment: you could start with parameter cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE to not lose any information during debugging